# List disk partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have installed Ubuntu in a Virtual Hard Disk on Windows (5G). So the problem I have is, the command **fdisk -l** shows me only the partition table of the Virtual Hard Disk as below:

```
`Device     Boot    Start       End    Sectors  Size  Id  Type
/dev/sda1   *        2048   9437183    9435136  4.5G  83  Linux
/dev/sda2         9439230  10483711     044482  510M   5  Extended
/dev/sda5         9439232  10483711    1044480  510M  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

so my question is there a way to list all system partitions (not only the ones of VHD) ?

**Note:** The path of my VHD is c:\users...\virtual machine\MyVHD.vhd

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual intention of a virtual machine is to provide an isolated environment, separated from the host's environment. You can not directly mount "real" partitions in the virtual machine, and, honestly, you shouldn't.

---

If you only want to access some files from within the VM, you can create host-guest shares. If you are using VirtualBox, this can be done by

1. Install the [VirtualBox guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) in the guest system.
2. Shut down the VM, open the VM Manager, select the Ubuntu VM and click *Settings*.
3. Go to *Shared folders* and create a new shared folder.
4. Boot the VM. You will find the shared folder in the network environment of the virtual system. You should be able to navigate there with the default file manager in Ubuntu.

---

In case you want to perform some repairs on your Windows partitions, forget it. This cannot be done from within a VM. If you want to natively access these partitions, use a live environment. To do this, extract the Ubuntu installation image to an USB stick using tools like [UnetBootin](http://unetbootin.github.io) or [PendriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/). After doing so, you should be able to boot off the USB and do whatever you wanted to do in the VM.

If you want to perform file system repairs, it is however the better choice to use Windows' own tools for this, like `chkdsk` or the automatic repair mechanisms on the installation disk.

Comment: Thanks a buch @the_seppi. That was very informative response.

Comment: @Amsbred If you are satisfied with this answer, please mark it as "answered" by clicking the tick mark.

Answer (score 0):

In linux if you have it installed on VHD your going to be limited to only seeing what's on the virtual hardware that the OS has access to in the virtual environment.

Comment: Undertstood and Resolved !